# Wildfly 24 / java 16 / Primefaces 10 / jakarta

Tags: java, primefaces, wildfly

The next exception, for which I currently have no answer...

After upgrading on Wildfly 24 and Java 16 there exception following  exception:

> 19:23:08,420 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."ROOT.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."ROOT.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "ROOT.war"
> at org.jboss.as.server@16.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:189 undefined)
> at org.jboss.msc@1.4.12.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739 undefined)
> at org.jboss.msc@1.4.12.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701 undefined)
> at org.jboss.msc@1.4.12.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559 undefined)
> at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35 undefined)
> at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990 undefined)
> at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486 undefined)
> at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1363 undefined)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831 undefined)
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/jboss/weld/environment/servlet/jsf/WeldApplicationFactory (Module "deployment.ROOT.war" from Service Module Loader): jakarta/faces/application/ApplicationFactory
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1010 undefined)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1088 undefined)
> at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:424 undefined)
> at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:555 undefined)
> at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:339 undefined)
> at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:126 undefined)
> at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:753 undefined)
> at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:247 undefined)
> at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410 undefined)
> at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398 undefined)
> at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116 undefined)
> at org.jboss.as.jsf@24.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.jsf.deployment.JSFComponentProcessor.installJsfArtifactComponent(JSFComponentProcessor.java:412 undefined)
> at org.jboss.as.jsf@24.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.jsf.deployment.JSFComponentProcessor.processJSFArtifactsForInjection(JSFComponentProcessor.java:297 undefined)
> at org.jboss.as.jsf@24.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.jsfment.JSFComponentProcessor.deploy.deploy(JSFComponentProcessor.java:244 undefined)
> at org.jboss.as.server@16.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:182 undefined)
> ... 8 more

Comment: My Wild-fly Faces has a PF Jakarta EE9 branch working fine. See: https://github.com/melloware/wildfly-faces/tree/jakartaee9

Comment: I'm not sure that Java 16 is a valid runtime for WildFly 24 given that currently it tries to support Java 17 in WildFly 25. Also you need to use wildfly24-preview (not the regular WildFly 24 dist) for JakartaEE 9 support

Answer (score 0):

the solution was the following dependency

> ```
>    <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
>       <artifactId>wildfly-jsf-injection</artifactId>
>       <version>24.0.1.Final</version>
>   </dependency>
> ```

now i have an another problem^^

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).